# How to make my website responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working on a site for a school project that's due today and I have tried what seems like everything to make it responsive correctly and no matter what it doesn't resize correctly. I'm not that knowledgeable with coding to begin with, and worried since this is due soon. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction as to how to get this to work for mobile devices and stuff? Thanks in advance.

The following is the CSS

```
    body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: default;
    color: #AAAAAA;
}
td {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: default;
    color: #242121
}
a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px
}
a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: underline
}
input {
    border-width: 1;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2px;
    height: 21px;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000
}
.slogan {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 0 0 10;
}
.class1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Times;
}
```

The following is one of the web pages: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Litter of Love</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="style-2.css" />
        <script>
            Alert("Welcome to my web page!") ;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="FFFFFF">
        <div align="center">
            <table width="750" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" width="750" height="200" background="header.jpg" valign="top" style="padding:0 0 0 10">
                        <table width="700" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="330" class="slogan">
                                    Build a Stylish Cat-Friendly Home
                                </td>
                                <td width="400" align="right">
                                    <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="right" height="20">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td width="20"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" height="15" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" height="1" bgcolor="CCCCCC"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" height="10" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="170" bgcolor="FFFFFF" valign="top">
                        <span style="font-size:6px"><br></span>
                        <div align="center">
                            <table width="140" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="5" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="about.html">About us</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="5" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="shop.html">Products</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="5" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="media.html">Media</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br><span style="font-size:6px"><br></span>
                            <span style="font-size:6px"><br></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="CCCCCC"></td>
                    <td width="579" valign="top">
                        <span style="font-size:6px"><br></span>
                        <div align="center">
                            <table width="549" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4" height="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" height="1" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" width="542" height="27" bgcolor="#334a10" class="class1">&nbsp;&nbsp;HEALTHY</td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" height="4" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0" height="23"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td colspan="2" height="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="FFFFFF">
                                        <table width="542" border="0" cellpadding="17" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="color:999999;line-height:1.6em">
                                                    <div align="justify"> 
                                                        <img src="healthy.jpg" width="350" height="200" align="left">
                                                        Put together an engaging jungle gym for your cat friend and provide the gift of satisfaction and longevity.
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        Made by eco friendly materials and production recycled packaging.
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td colspan="2" height="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" height="5" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                    <td width="4" height="5" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                    <td width="538" height="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                    <td width="1" height="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                    <td width="5" height="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br>
                            <table width="549" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4" height="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" height="1" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" width="542" height="27" bgcolor="#334a10" class="class1">&nbsp;&nbsp;FUNCTIONAL
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" height="4" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0" height="23"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td colspan="2" height="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="FFFFFF">
                                        <table width="542" border="0" cellpadding="17" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="color:999999;line-height:1.6em">
                                                    <div align="justify"> 
                                                        <img src="functional.jpg"  width="350" height="200" align="right">
                                                        Captivating, durable and easy to relocate. Our cat furniture designs are a space conscious alternative to the traditional commercial cat tree.
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td colspan="2" height="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" height="5" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                    <td width="4" height="5" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                    <td width="538" height="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                    <td width="1" height="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                    <td width="5" height="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br>
                            <table width="549" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4" height="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" height="1" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" width="542" height="27" bgcolor="#334a10" class="class1">&nbsp;&nbsp;MODERN</td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" height="4" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0" height="23"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td colspan="2" height="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="FFFFFF">
                                        <table width="542" border="0" cellpadding="17" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="color:999999;line-height:1.6em">
                                                    <div align="justify">
                                                        <img src="beautiful.jpg" width="350" height="200" align="left">
                                                        We believe furniture should be noticed, but not draw too much attention. We design conceps which spark conversation in any home, and yet stand the test of time. We are thrilled to see cats coming out of the unnoticed rooms and into your modern living room. 
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td colspan="2" height="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="1" bgcolor="AAAAAA"></td>
                                    <td width="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="1" height="5" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                    <td width="4" height="5" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                                    <td width="538" height="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                    <td width="1" height="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                    <td width="5" height="5" bgcolor="F0F0F0"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <span style="font-size:6px"><br></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" height="10" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" height="1" bgcolor="CCCCCC"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" height="5" bgcolor="FFFFFF"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="FFFFFF" align="right">
                        Valco Copyright © 2017 All Rights Reserved 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: look into `@media` querys

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp Refer this

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wondering why you get a horizontal scrollbar on a narrower screen than 766 pixels?

Comment: Also... *tables* for layout is 1990s stuff.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Sorry I've changed the title to hopefully a better one.

Comment: Don't use `table`, `tr`,`td` - that's a mess for responsiveness. Use nested `div` elements instead and give them a percentage width relative to their parent container. Make the `body` width 100%. Use CSS media queries to set breakpoints where elements switch from desktop layout (say 70/30% width next to each other) to mobile (100% width). Alt: look up `flexbox` on CSS-tricks. Don't put font sizes & colors in the HTML - instead use CSS to create/apply classes to various & elements. Start your homework earlier & ask for help sooner than the day a project is due when it's too late.

Comment: And even in the 20th century, your HTML would have been full of errors. Have you noticed how none of the bgcolors work, except the ones starting with `#`, and that the Alert isn't shown?

Comment: I learned years ago which is why I'm a bit clueless now when it comes to the modern stuff, bootsrap and all that is new to me so I'm having a bit of trouble in this class since I've learned it another way. Thanks for the suggestions thus far though, I'll try to make sense of it and attempt to try again.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest would be to use a responsive css framework, and use existing components, and if needed configure/style them as your needs be.

I would recommend [Bootstrap](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.0/docs/getting-started/), you can see some page example [here](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.0/docs/getting-started/#examples).

For the side navigation, you could use [Navs > Pills (stacked)](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.0/docs/components/#nav-pills), each right section could be using [Panels > Panel with heading](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.0/docs/components/#panels-heading) and inside each panel you could have [Media Object](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.0/docs/components/#media)

This would be much nicer than using `<table>` layout as you seem to be doing right now.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a "quick" way to make your website responsive. You should look into media queries.

They are super smart and you use them directly in your CSS.

Make one for desktop, tablet and mobile and you should be good to go :)

See here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp